Rails routing for nested routes that reference the same object as the parent
I would like to generate a routes like this:
/appointments/:id/pricing/edit
/appointments/:id/pricing/update

Assuming I already have this in my routes:
resources :appointments

There is no ID for a pricing, it's the same Appointment object, found by the same ID.
I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

You can do this:
resources :appointments do
  # adds routes to /appointments/:id
  member do
    # singular `resource` does not add :id
    resource :pricing, only: [:edit, :update]
  end
end

which generates:
      Prefix Verb  URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
edit_pricing GET   /appointments/:id/pricing/edit(.:format) pricings#edit
     pricing PATCH /appointments/:id/pricing(.:format)      pricings#update


If you really need to have /update in the url:
resources :appointments do
  member do
    resource :pricing, only: [] do
      get "edit"
      patch "update"
    end
  end
end

      Prefix Verb  URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
edit_pricing GET   /appointments/:id/pricing/edit(.:format)   pricings#edit
     pricing PATCH /appointments/:id/pricing/update(.:format) pricings#update

or
resources :appointments do
  member do
    get "pricing/edit",     to: "pricings#edit"
    patch "pricing/update", to: "pricings#update"
  end
end

                   Prefix Verb  URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
  pricing_edit_appointment GET   /appointments/:id/pricing/edit(.:format)   pricings#edit
pricing_update_appointment PATCH /appointments/:id/pricing/update(.:format) pricings#update

or
resources :appointments do
  member do
    scope :pricing, controller: :pricings, as: :pricing do
      get "edit"
      patch "update"
    end
  end
end

                  Prefix Verb  URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
edit_pricing_appointment GET   /appointments/:id/pricing/edit(.:format)   pricings#edit
     pricing_appointment PATCH /appointments/:id/pricing/update(.:format) pricings#update


Just stick to the conventions instead. This will let you use the polymorphic route helpers as intended and make future maintainers happy.
resources :appointments do
  resource :pricing, only: [:edit, :update]
end

As well as the standard routes generated by resources :appointments this generates the routes for a singular nested resource.
                  Prefix Verb  URI Pattern                                          Controller#Action
edit_appointment_pricing GET   /appointments/:appointment_id/pricing/edit(.:format) pricings#edit
     appointment_pricing PATCH /appointments/:appointment_id/pricing(.:format)      pricings#update
                         PUT   /appointments/:appointment_id/pricing(.:format)      pricings#update

In Rails the "action" is implied through the HTTP verb and not by a postfix on  the path with the exception of new and edit which just exist to render forms.
When dealing with a nested resource the parent id parameter takes the form :appointment_id not :id. This avoids any potential ambigiuty.
Even with singular resources the controller name is still plural.
